# Faulty TPMS what can I do?

Tags: peugeot, tire-pressure-monitoring-system, peugeot-207

basically I bought my Peugeot 207cc last year(make from 2010). The dealership sold it with a faulty TPMS . I have now changed the faulty TPMS and the light still comes up. What can it be?
The garage who did said they can't reset it cus of the model of the car is too old for their diagnostic machine or soming like that and also said I have 2 TPMS that give the same code when reading it and apparently shouldn't be? I don'twant to spend 300 odd quid on replacing the rest of the TPMS and still hav the same issue at the end. What else can I do? Even tho I know that MOT failure is only for car models from 2012 onwards with TPMS issues but I still don't want to risk it and it's bloody annoying the warning ligth every time I drive it. Any suggestions?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The car almost certainly needs to be programmed with the proper equipment to recognize the new TPMS module.  If the shop you went to doesn't have the correct equipment, find another one or go to the dealer.

Did you check if the old module could be rebuilt?  Usually all they need is a new battery and a gasket or o-ring?  That would eliminate the need to get the car re-programmed.

Comment: No I didn't check as I wasn't aware that could be a possibility. They wanted to charge me to change all of the tpms and I was like... absolutely not! Lol but thank you for getting back to me I'll try to find out what type of tpms is and see if can get reprogrammed else we're, cheers